# Powershell: Pass result of Get-AzTableRow to function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am using below PowerShell code in azure functions to retrieve rows of users in azure table who belongs to a particular location.

`$Rows = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -customFilter "((Location eq '$loc') and (PartitionKey eq 'User'))"`

Next, I need to pass the result (`$Rows`) of the above query to a function as parameter. Tried to define the function as

```
function display_rows($param){
   $tempcount = $param.Count
   for($i=0; $i -lt $tempcount; $i++){
        ...code body...
    }
}
```

and invoke the function as `display_rows "$Rows"`. But it seems it's not working as intended. Is this the proper way to pass the result of `Get-AzTableRow` to a function? please help me with this.

Comment: remove the double quotes around the inbound $Var. that converts it to a simple STRING object ... and you appear to want the _complex_ object to remain such.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thanks for your advice, it resolved the issue for me. Can you post it as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: done! [*grin*] please let me know if i got the idea across with sufficient clarity.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yep, the answer you posted was very descriptive and helpful

Comment: kool! thank you for the feedback ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the basic problem is that you are sending a "stringified" version of the object to the function. [*grin*]

when you do ...

```
display_rows "$Rows"
```

... are not sending the object in `$Rows` to the function. you are converting that object into a string and sending *that*.

**that simple string object aint what you want. [*grin*] you want the complex object instead.**

so, the fix is to NOT wrap `$Rows` in double quotes. just use it bare, like so ...

```
display_rows $Rows
```

that will send the object contained in the $Var to the function, not the `.ToString()` of that object.

---

as an aside, you otta NEVER use quotes around a $Var unless you are sure you need them.